# "/usr/bin/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";?

Tags: command, c

I found this line in the [if.c](http://v6shell.org/history/if.c) of unix version 6.

```
ncom = "/usr/bin/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
```

Why are there so many x's?
And why would you set this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The code you are talking of looks like this:

```
ncom = "/usr/bin/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
while(c=nargv[0][i])  {
    ncom[9+i++] = c;
}
ncom[9+i] = '\0';
```

All those x's act as a buffer, they are overridden by the following loop.
Therefore the code effectively adds "/usr/bin/" to the command in `nargv[0]`.

With a little more context the code is doing this:

```
execv(nargv[0], nargv, np);
execv(ncom+4, nargv, np);
execv(ncom, nargv, np);
```

If the given command in `nargv[0]` is `"foo"` it will first try to run `"foo"` then `"/bin/foo"` and finally `"/usr/bin/foo"`.

---

Be aware that above is a good example how to **not** do such things:

If the string in `nargv[0]` happens to be longer than the number of x's, the code will happily continue copying data. This will override other parts of the stack. The result is a good example of a buffer overflow. (You allocate a buffer of some size and write more data than allocated.)

This example will demonstrate the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  char s[]="abcde";
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    printf("position %2d contains value %3d\n",i,s[i]);
    s[i]=0;
  }
  puts(s);
  return 0;
}
```

If you run it it will (most probably) output this:

```
position  0 contains value  97
position  1 contains value  98
position  2 contains value  99
position  3 contains value 100
position  4 contains value 101
position  5 contains value   0
position  6 contains value   0
position  7 contains value   0
position  8 contains value   0
position  9 contains value   0
position 10 contains value   0
position 11 contains value   0
position 12 contains value  12
position  1 contains value   0
position  2 contains value   0
position  3 contains value   0
position  4 contains value   0
position  5 contains value   0
position  6 contains value   0
position  7 contains value   0
[...]
```

It will fill the string (containing the ASCII values 97 to 101) with zeroes and continue writing the memory where it will find the position of the variable `i` it will also set it to zero. Now `i` is zero and therefore the loop starts again, overriding the the already overridden string again and again.

Not only local variables can be overriden, also the return address of a function might get overriden resulting in either a "segmentation fault" or execution of arbitrary code, which is often used by malware.

Comment: Why +9 and +4? 
Thank you michas :)

Comment: The numbers are positions in the string: "/usr" are 4 characters. "/usr/bin/" are 9 characters.

Comment: Ah now I see it :) Thank you again michas!

Comment: What if we <strike>needed</strike> tried to run a command with a name longer than 35 chars?

Comment: Yes this is a good example how to **not** do such things, as this will create a buffer overflow. (Answer updated.)

Comment: Not to mention, `ncom` is pointing at a *string literal* which is then modified - a big no-no in modern-day C, where string literals are often stored in read-only memory.

Comment: Although the `ncom` code here is not an example of good defensive programming, in practice the string was long enough for a user using the program properly, because in V6, you'd never need to run a pathname-less command (one without a '/' character somewhere in the command name) that was longer than 14 characters, because that was the longest an entry in a directory could be. Used improperly, I guess it would overwrite data used by `libc`.